# Pygame Sprite won't Move but there's no errors?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I need some help. I can't move the paddle sprite and there are no errors that come up either on the Idle. The Image comes up on the window but it doesn't move up or down. I'm trying to make a simple Pong game and any tips or tricks would be really appreciated. Here is the code guys.

```
import pygame
import random
from Colors3 import *

WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 650
FPS = 30

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class PaddleB(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("BluePaddle.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(20,80))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 20
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2
        self.keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.vel = 5
        self.speedy = 0

    def draw(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        self.speedy = 0

        if key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.speedy = -5
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.speedy = 5

        self.rect.y += self.speedy



def Drawn():
    all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    paddle1 = PaddleB()
    all_sprites.add(paddle1)
    all_sprites.update()
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()


# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    Drawn()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You are recreating all of your sprites every time the `Drawn()` function is called. You need to separate your initialisation so that it is called before you start the game loop. Maybe look at this [page](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html) describing game loops.

Answer (score 1):

I've rearranged your code a little and changed the event handling so that the <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>↓</kbd> will move the paddle. Added a few comments to make the code clearer and made the initial paddle position to be the centre of the window.

I've updated the game loop to follow the *Event Handling* → *Game State Update* → *Display Update* pattern as described in this [book](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english3e/pygame.html).

```
import pygame
import random
# from Colors3 import *

WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 650
FPS = 30

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class PaddleB(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        # self.image = pygame.image.load("BluePaddle.png")
        # self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image,(20,80))
        # create an image instead of loading one.
        self.image = pygame.Surface((20, 80))
        self.image.fill(pygame.color.Color("blue"))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # start paddle in the middle of the window, on the left
        self.rect.x = 20
        self.rect.y = HEIGHT / 2 - self.rect.height / 2
        self.vel = 5
        self.speedy = 0

    def update(self):
        # this will move the sprite based on its speed
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        # TODO: Check limits here to prevent off screen movement.

# Setup game
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
paddle1 = PaddleB()
all_sprites.add(paddle1)
pygame.display.set_caption("Half Pong!")
# Game loop
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddle1.speedy -= paddle1.vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddle1.speedy += paddle1.vel
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                paddle1.speedy += paddle1.vel
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                paddle1.speedy -= paddle1.vel
    # update game elements
    all_sprites.update()
    # draw surface
    window.fill(pygame.color.Color("grey"))
    all_sprites.draw(window)
    # show surface
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick(FPS)
pygame.quit()
```

Let me know if you need any additional clarifications.

Comment: Yeah, that helped a lot thanks. I added another class called PaddleC now all I need is to help me make a ball that moves around the screen in one direction and how to detect a collision. You got any tips that can help?

Comment: There are pygame functions to detect sprite collision, [e.g](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide). Also, instead of creating another paddle class, perhaps your existing class can be made more generic to support both left and right paddles. You can add parameters to the constructor to make it easier to instantiate different types of paddle, e.g. position, colour